# Can I watch the submit button or function in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I've got a question about the Vue watcher function. Can I watch the function? for example:
when I click the submit button, the watch listens the submit button and handles the function in the watcher.

```
<b-table :fields="tableFields" :items="itemOfProps"/>
```

```
<b-modal
     :ok.prevent="saveGrant" 
     form fields bla2
      ....
</b-modal>
```

in script:

```
async saveGrant() {
     sends the fields of b-modal as post

},
```

```
async getProps() {
     sends the get request to server
     itemOfProps = {response.data}
}
```

in here watcher:

```
watch: {
here I need to watch b-modal's submit button or saveGrant
and re-call getProps() to render b-table again.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't watch a function.

If your goal is to run `getProps` again when `saveGrant` finishes, you can use `await` for that:

```
async saveGrant() {
    // sends the fields of b-modal as post
    const result = await myRequestCall();
    // now myRequestCall is done
    this.getProps();
}
```

Comment: Thank you much. I found a solution that I can define another function that claims saveGrant, getProps functions.
``` 
async refresh() {
          await this.saveGrant();
          await this.getProps();
}
```